# When to use 云う vs 言う?

Tags: word-choice, usage, kanji, nuances, homophonic-kanji

They're both pronounced the same, and seem to mean the same thing; is there a difference, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Broadly speaking, 云う seems to be somewhat more old-fashioned in use.  It appears with some frequency in Natsume Soseki's works, but not so much in recent publications, which use 言う instead.

[The Weblio page giving the Daijirin entry](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BA%91%E3%81%86) show that the 言う spelling is *jōyō*, while the 云う spelling is not (the black downward-pointing triangle indicates non-*jōyō* characters).  Moreover, towards the bottom of the long entry, we get this:

> (2) 漢字表記は現代では「言」が主に用いられる。古くは❸ ③ には「云」がよく用いられ，「謂」は「いわば」「いわゆる」の場合に用いられた。
>
> (2) For the kanji spelling, 言 is the main modern usage.  In older times, 云 was often used for sense ❸ ③ [*note: prefaced as* （「…だと言う」「…と言う」の形で）], and 謂 was used for いわば{iwaba} and いわゆる{iwayuru}.

Comment: NOTE: Due to licensing changes for Daijirin, that dictionary has disappeared from various online dictionary aggregator sites, such as Weblio or Kotobank.  Daijisen is still included (as of 2021-04-19), and their notation for non-Jōyō kanji is a × mark instead.